# how to attach text file to mandrill mail in parse cloud code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, mandrill

how to attach text file to mandrill mail in parse cloud code.
I am trying to attach file which are store in parse cloud and send that file as attachment in mandrill mail.

Answer (score 1):

According to their API Docs is does look like it is possible: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html

However, you would have to encode it to a `base64-encoded string`.

Comment: thanks for your solution , but is it possible to read content from stored flie in parse class and then send it as a attachment through madrill ?